# ldead/lag or diff functions with apply

Tags: r

I have trouble using correctly `diff` and `lead/lag` from `dplyr` package combined with `apply` function - it keeps producing `NA` or `NaN`. As example Im using percentage change over previous period(with `diff`), but this problem is shared by all my formulas that include `diff` and `lead/lag`.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
#training data frame
mydat=data.frame(matrix(c(1:10,11:20),nrow=10,ncol=2))
#example apply code
apply(mydat[1],1,function(x) c( NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)]))
```

in this case the result is:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What is wrong here? I just started using `apply` instead `for` everywhere.

Comment: You are selecting one column and then applying `diff` on row where there is only a single obs.  Probably you meant `apply(mydat,2,function(x) c( NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)]))` or use `lapply`

Comment: Ok, this actually works fine, but in my final code i use nested apply function so lest say code look like this: `apply(df[,1:2],1,function(y) c(NA,diff(y[1])/y[1][-length(y[1])]))`. Now it gives me string of `NA`.  What am I missing here?